# Почему при SQL запросе "цепляются" не все строки

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть 3 таблицы.
table 1 (Общие данные по продажам) - в ней 3 поля: код менеджера, тип продажи, сумма в рублях
table 2 (Менеджеры продающие за рубли в Москве)- в ней 2 поля: код менеджера, ФИО
table 3 (Менеджеры продающие за доллары в Москве и Казани) - в ней 2 поля: код менеджера, ФИО
Менеджеры 2 и 3 таблицах могут повторяться.

Мне нужно вывести ФИО менеджеров продающих в Москве и сумму продаж.
Написал вот такой запрос, все работает, но почему то из table_3 подтягивает не всех.
Подскажите где ошибка?

```
SELECT table_3.ФИО_менеджера, SUM(table_1.Продажи_руб) FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.Код_менеджера=table_2.Код_менеджера
INNER JOIN table_3 ON table_1.Код_менеджера=table_3.Код_менеджера
WHERE table_3.Город='Москва'
GROUP BY table_3.ФИО_менеджера
```

Comment: Почему вы так решили? У вас из table_3 вытянутся все данные по вашему фильтру с ограничением, что этот ID_менеджера есть в остальных таблицах

Comment: Возможно в table_3.Город данные не 'Москва', а что-то вроде '  Москва   '. используйте LIKE '%Москва%' для проверки

Comment: Потому что я для тестов создал таблицы и у меня в таблице_3 - 2 менеджера, которые продают в Москве, а подтягивается только 1(

Comment: При `INNER JOIN` ваши 2 менеджера из table_3 должны быть в table_2 и table_1

Comment: Так, вот методом проб, я понял, что если удалить запрос к table_2, то из table_3 все подтягивается.
Подскажите что тогда использовать, что бы объединить все

Comment: Все, закрываю) Помог LEFT JOIN, спасибо за ответы